# DesignGridLayout goes out of boundaries

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, layout-manager

My problem is this code producing a Swing GUI, goes out of display bounds in my laptop. Why?
It's using DesignGridLayout as layout library.

This is a code taken from answer in: [Why does my components go out of boundaries, please help me to align it with the necessary code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22041915/why-does-my-components-go-out-of-boundaries-please-help-me-to-align-it-with-the)[image]

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import net.java.dev.designgridlayout.DesignGridLayout;

public class Demo {

    private void createAndShowGUI() {

        JLabel i5l1 = new JLabel("FREIGHT DETAILS");
        JLabel i5l2 = new JLabel("Date : ");
        JLabel i5l3 = new JLabel("Vehicle No. : ");
        JLabel i5l4 = new JLabel("From : ");
        JLabel i5l5 = new JLabel("Item : ");
        JLabel i5l6 = new JLabel("Quantity : ");
        JLabel i5l7 = new JLabel("Kg.");
        JLabel i5l8 = new JLabel("Rate :                                          Rs.");
        JLabel i5l15 = new JLabel("SALE DETAILS");
        JLabel i5l16 = new JLabel("Cash Sales :                             Rs. ");
        JLabel i5l17 = new JLabel("Credit :                                       Rs. ");
        JLabel i5l18 = new JLabel("EXPENSES");
        JLabel i5l19 = new JLabel("Food & Tea :                            Rs. ");
        JLabel i5l20 = new JLabel("Wages :                                   Rs. ");
        JLabel i5l21 = new JLabel("Miscellaneous Expenses :     Rs. ");

        JTextField i5t1 = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField i5t2 = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField i5t3 = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField i5t4 = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField i5t11 = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField i5t12 = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField i5t13 = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField i5t14 = new JTextField(20);

        JComboBox i5cb1 = new JComboBox<>();
        JComboBox i5cb2 = new JComboBox<>();
        JComboBox i5cb3 = new JComboBox<>();

        JButton i5b1 = new JButton("Save");
        JButton i5b2 = new JButton("Reset"); 
        JButton i5b3 = new JButton("Close");

        JSeparator i5sep1 = new JSeparator();
        JSeparator i5sep2 = new JSeparator();
        JSeparator i5sep3 = new JSeparator();
        JSeparator i5sep4 = new JSeparator();
        JSeparator i5sep5 = new JSeparator();
        JSeparator i5sep6 = new JSeparator();

        Object[] columnNames = new Object[]{"Column # 1", "Column # 2", "Column # 3", "Column # 4"};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 10);
        JTable table = new JTable(model);

        JScrollPane i5t1sp1 = new JScrollPane(table);

        JPanel freightPanel = new JPanel();
        DesignGridLayout layout1 = new DesignGridLayout(freightPanel);

        layout1.row().left().add(i5sep1).fill().withOwnRowWidth();
        layout1.row().center().add(i5l1);
        layout1.row().left().add(i5sep2).fill().withOwnRowWidth();
        layout1.row().grid(i5l2).add(i5t1);
        layout1.row().grid(i5l3).add(i5t2);
        layout1.row().grid(i5l4).add(i5cb1);
        layout1.row().grid(i5l5).add(i5cb2);
        layout1.row().grid(i5l6).add(i5t3).add(i5l7);
        layout1.row().grid(i5l8).add(i5t4);

        layout1.row().left().add(i5sep5).fill().withOwnRowWidth();
        layout1.row().center().add(i5l18);
        layout1.row().left().add(i5sep6).fill().withOwnRowWidth();
        layout1.row().grid(i5l19).add(i5t12);
        layout1.row().grid(i5l20).add(i5t13);
        layout1.row().grid(i5l21).add(i5t14);

        JPanel salePanel = new JPanel();
        DesignGridLayout layout2 = new DesignGridLayout(salePanel);

        layout2.row().left().add(i5sep3).fill().withOwnRowWidth();
        layout2.row().center().add(i5l15);
        layout2.row().left().add(i5sep4).fill().withOwnRowWidth();
        layout2.row().grid(i5l16).add(i5t11);
        layout2.row().grid(i5l17).add(i5cb3);
        layout2.row().grid().add(i5t1sp1);

        JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("Daily Analysis",true,true, true, true);        

        DesignGridLayout mainLayout = new DesignGridLayout(internalFrame.getContentPane());
        mainLayout.row().grid().add(freightPanel).add(salePanel);
        mainLayout.row().left().add(new JSeparator()).fill().withOwnRowWidth();
        mainLayout.row().center().add(i5b1).add(i5b2).add(i5b3);

        internalFrame.pack();
        internalFrame.setVisible(true);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(internalFrame);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Demo().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, why not?

`pack()` makes the frames take the size they need to display all their subcomponents properly (according to their preferred size and fulfilling min/max restrictions), If they have a lot to show and/or your resolution is not big enough the window may end up being out of bounds of your screen. This would be a surprising issue if, say, the frame was maximized.

Comment: Weather there is pack() or not in code, GUI goes out of bounds. Why does those components take so much space?

Comment: @user3422747 For me without both(!) packs the frame has size 0. But yes, the core "problem" is that the components want to take a lot of space. Why is that depends on the nature of the components and the `LayoutManager`  (DesignGridLayout). For example, try disabling the first 2 lines with adds on the `mainLayout` so you only have `mainLayout.row().center().add(i5b1).add(i5b2).add(i5b3);` you can see that now the frame is small because that is the space that the buttons are asking for.

Comment: Yes, indeed if I remove 2 first lines of mainpanel added, then it remain only button added there and panel is very small.
Actually I'm wondering, why those other components take so much space, eg text field?